# Set value of field in Firestore document only if the field hasn't already been set

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection whose documents look something like this:

```
count: number
first: timestamp
last: timestamp
```

The `first` value should (almost) never change after the document's creation.

In a batch write operation, I am trying to update documents in this collection, or create those documents that do not yet exist. Something like

```
batch.setData([
    "count": FieldValue.increment(someInteger),
    "first": someTimestamp,
    "last": someTimestamp
    ], forDocument: someDocumentRef, mergeFields: ["count","last"])
```

My *hope* was that by excluding `first` from the `mergeFields` array, Firestore would set `count` and `last` by merging it into an existing document or making a new one, and set `first` only if it had no previous value (i.e., the document didn't exist before this operation). It is clear to me now that this is not the case, and instead `first` is completely ignored. Now I'm left wondering what the Firestore team intended for this situation.

I know that I could achieve this with a Transaction, but that doesn't tie in very well with my batch write. Are Transactions my only option, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: This would be a fantastic feature for "created" timestamp fields which we put on basically every document. It would be great to avoid the read step. Sadly it doesn't seem to exist today.

Answer (score 2):

I have created timestamps and other data in my documents and I handle this using separate create and update functions rather than trying to do it all at once.

The initial creation function includes the created date etc and then subsequent updates use the non-destructive update, so just omit any fields in the update payload you do not want to overwrite.

eg. to create:

```
batch.set(docRef, {created: someTimestamp, lastUpdate: someTimestamp})
```

then to update:

```
batch.update(docRef, {lastUpdate: someTimestamp, someOtherField: someData})
```

This will not overwrite the creationDate field or any other fields, but will create the someOtherField if it does not exist.

If you have a need to do a "only update existing fields" update after the document is created for the first time then currently you have to read the document first to find out if the fields exist and then create an update payload which will patch the only the desired fields. This can be done in a transaction or you can write this logic yourself, depending on your needs.